# Add attribute to the filtred div

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, toggle

```js
jQuery(document).ready(filter);

function filter() {
    jQuery(".my-divs").each(function () {
        jQuery(".my-divs div").filter(function () {
            jQuery(this).toggle(jQuery(this).text() <= 3);
        });
    });
 
    jQuery(".my-divs div").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
            jQuery(this).attr('data-filtred', 'true');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.my-divs div {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
<hr></hr>
<div id="2" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

I have some function who filter `tr` `div`'s by toggling them, So I need to add attribute the to the toggled div (div that are visible).

The filter works fine, I just want to add attribute `data-filtred="true"` to the elements thats visible

```
function filter() 
    jQuery(".my-divs").each(function () {
        jQuery(".my-divs tr").filter(function () {
            jQuery(this).toggle((new Date(jQuery(this).find('td.date').data('basedate')).getTime() >= (from) && new Date(jQuery(this).find('td.date').data('basedate')).getTime() <= (to)));
        });
    });
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
function filter() 
    jQuery(".my-divs").each(function () {
        jQuery(".my-divs tr").filter(function () {
            jQuery(this).toggle((new Date(jQuery(this).find('td.date').data('basedate')).getTime() >= (from) && new Date(jQuery(this).find('td.date').data('basedate')).getTime() <= (to)));
        });
    });

    jQuery(".my-divs tr").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
            jQuery(this).attr('data-filtred', 'true');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve], it'll help to play with your sample and understand what's bothering you by seeing the actual HTML and the minimal CSS (if needed)

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan it's done, but on the other hand on this example, it works, I'll check my code why

Comment: why are you using filter but not really using filter? You are using it as an each...

Comment: `jQuery(".my-divs").each(function () {
        jQuery(".my-divs div").filter(function () {`<-- You end up looping a ton of times also for no reason. The seelction inside is selecting all of the .my-divs, it is not working on the current one in the outer loop.

Comment: FYI: hr element does not have a closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of filter is wrong. The correct way to use filter would be to return a boolean so it alters the jQuery collection.

```js
$(".my-divs div").filter( function () {
  return Number($(this).text()) < 3
}).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="2" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

But I do not think filter is the best thing to use since you need to do actions on both sets. So an each loop is fine

```js
$(".my-divs div").each( function () {
  var div = $(this)
  if (Number(div.text()) < 3) {
    div
      .removeAttr("data-filtred")
      .removeData("filtered")
      .hide()
  } else {
    div
      .setAttr("data-filtred", "true")
      .data("filtered", "true")
      .show()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="2" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filter() 
    jQuery(".my-divs").each(function () {
        jQuery(".my-divs tr").filter(function () {
            jQuery(this).toggle((new Date(jQuery(this).find('td.date').data('basedate')).getTime() >= (from) && new Date(jQuery(this).find('td.date').data('basedate')).getTime() <= (to)));
        });
    });

    jQuery(".my-divs tr").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
            **jQuery(".my-divs tr").removeAttr('data-filtred');**
            jQuery(this).attr('data-filtred', 'true');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you want to use the **data-*** attributes, but I know how to handle some situations.

First of all, if you need to add/change some **data-*** attribute, there's the [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function - and in case if you need to remove, [.removeData()](https://api.jquery.com/removedata/).

I changed your code a little bit, just to remove some unecessary code.
It is setting `data-filtered` as `true` or `false` depending on your filter condition.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(filter);

function filter() {
    jQuery(".my-divs div").each(function () {
        let el = jQuery(this);
        let filter = el.text() <= 3;
        el.data('filtered', filter);
        el.toggle(filter);
    });
}
```

```css
.my-divs div {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
<hr></hr>
<div id="2" class="my-divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution has issues because it is reusing the bad code from the OP.